# Why my Mysql simple insert stuck on so long with "STATE: update"?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Always get stuck on the simple insert sql blow with `STATE: update`, it can execute successfully like 15 minutes after, but why so long?

The query and table schema is below:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where info like '%4fun%' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     ID: 26394242
   USER: vtube
   HOST: 10.75.64.65:58622
     DB: vtubemeta
COMMAND: Query
   TIME: 0
  STATE: executing
   INFO: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where info like '%4fun%'
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     ID: 26449261
   USER: vtube
   HOST: 10.75.64.65:56658
     DB: vtubemeta
COMMAND: Query
   TIME: 150
  STATE: update
   INFO: insert into spider_4fun_video_meta
                        (`poster_id`,`pubtime`,`country`,`play_cnt`,`share_cnt`,
                                `comment_cnt`,`like_cnt`,`vid`,
                                `msg_txt`,`app_name`,`status`)
                        values('39CCE0695EB495B4',1556715312,'IN',2592,72,
                                4,122,'22729715',
                                '','4fun',0)
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                            play_cnt=Values(play_cnt),
share_cnt=Values(share_cnt),
comment_cnt=Values(comment_cnt),
like_cnt=Values(like_cnt),
msg_txt=Values(msg_txt)
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `spider_4fun_video_meta` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `poster_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `pubtime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `country` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `play_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `share_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `like_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_txt` text,
  `status` int(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` varchar(254) DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `idx_posterId` (`poster_id`),
  KEY `idx_country_status_pubtime` (`country`,`status`,`pubtime`),
  KEY `idx_country_status_likeCnt` (`country`,`status`,`like_cnt`),
  KEY `idx_country_status_priority` (`country`,`status`,`priority`),
  KEY `idx_update_time` (`update_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=96249089 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

==================

It can execute "simliar insert" smoothly for 5minutes (execute 300times maybe), and get heavily stuck like the query above, one single Thread.

Comment: Perhaps some user other than `vtube` is running a big query (eg, `ALTER`) against the table?  (And you don't have permissions to see his queries.)